# Using variables with heroku-buildpack-static

Tags: heroku, monorepo

I have a monorepo containing, among other things, a React app. I'm using The [create-react-app Buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack), which uses [heroku-buildpack-static](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static) to serve stuff.

Since the app is in `foo/examples/bar`, I've created the following `static.json`:

```
{
  "root": "foo/examples/${EXAMPLE}/build/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

And an `EXAMPLE` config var with the value `bar`. According to the [docs](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static#interpolating-env-var-values), this should work.

When the app is built by heroku, I see this in the log:

```
app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] unknown "example" variable
app[web.1]: Process exited unexpectedly: nginx
app[web.1]: Going down, terminating child processes...
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Is there a way to fix this build, or a better way to deploy this kind of repo?

Comment: Do you have a minimal repo for this which I can deploy and test?

Comment: @TarunLalwani not minimal but this is the actual repo: https://github.com/HerbCaudill/cevitxe. I'm trying to deploy the grid example.

Comment: Cool, checking now

Comment: Please join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197289/discussion-for-using-variables-with-heroku-buildpack-static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your main `buildpack` is [create-react-app-buildpack](https://github.com/tarunlalwani/create-react-app-buildpack).

Which then uses 3 `buildpacks` as seen at [create-react-app-buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/.buildpacks)

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-inner-buildpack.git#v9.0.0
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git
```

The feature you are looking for is in the buildpack `heroku-buildpack-static`. If we look at the source code of the same

There are only 3 variables which support interpolation, we can see the same at

[heroku-buildpack-static](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static/blob/8bea3b3d31ddd9a9672c84b567af13e3d7427138/scripts/config/lib/nginx_config.rb#L31)

Now for us to get interpolation in `root` variable as well, we need to modify the code like

```rb
json["root"] ||= DEFAULT[:root]
json["root"] = NginxConfigUtil.interpolate(json["root"], ENV) if json["root"]
```

So I forked the repo to update the same

[heroku-buildpack-static](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static/blob/8bea3b3d31ddd9a9672c84b567af13e3d7427138/scripts/config/lib/nginx_config.rb#L31)

But since the buildpacks are defined in [create-react-app-buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack), so we need to fork that and update the `.buildpacks` file as done below

[create-react-app-buildpack](https://github.com/tarunlalwani/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/.buildpacks)

Now after that we use this forked repo as our build pack

```sh
$ heroku config:set  JS_RUNTIME_TARGET_BUNDLE="/app/packages/examples/grid/build/static/js/*.js"
$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/tarunlalwani/heroku-buildpack-static.git
$ heroku config:set  EXAMPLE=grid
$ heroku push origin master
```

And now the build works fine

[image: Working fine]